# Overload chaining of arithmetic operators in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

In my classes, I often use overloading like in [this site](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading) to define their behavior when using operators like `+`,`-`, etc. by overwriting the `__add__`,`__sub__`, etc. methods.

An example would be this:

```
class MyClass:    
    def __add__(self, other):
        result = my_custom_adder(self, other)
        return self.__class__(result)
```

*Is there any way to define the behavior when chaining of such overwritten operators?*

For example, an addition of three elements `a + b + c` of a complex class could be implemented much more efficiently by taking all three elements into account at once and not just calculating `(a + b) + c` sequentially.

Of cause I can just introduce a classmethod:

```
class MyClass:    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.my_custom_adder(self, other)

    @classmethod
    def my_custom_adder(cls, *args):
        result = do_efficient_addition(*args)
        return cls(result)
```

Then, I can call `my_custom_adder(a, b, c)` instead. But this requires the user to know that there is a method like this and calling it explicitly, instead of just using `a + b + c`.

Comment: Not possible. `+` is a binary operator (i.e. it takes 2 arguments) and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks Aran-Fey. My question was a bit more general than the one you marked this as a duplicate of, but the answer fits nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't really anything for such hook methods to know that they are part of a larger equation.

What you could do is produce an *intermediate result object*, one that collects the objects and only when you need the *outcome* do the actual calculation.

For example, if your objects are integer-like, and implements the [`__int__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) to facilitate conversions, an intermediary value could postpone the calculation until then:

```
class BaseIntValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = ', '.join([f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in vars(self).items()])
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({attrs})'
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, BaseIntValue):
            return NotImplemented
        return IntermediarySummedIntValue(self, other)

class IntermediarySummedIntValue(BaseIntValue):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.values = values
    def __int__(self):
        print("Expensive calculation taking place")
        return sum(map(int, self.values))
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, BaseIntValue):
            return NotImplemented
        if isinstance(other, IntermediarySummedIntValue):
            values = self.values + other.values
        else:
            values = self.values + (other,)
        return IntermediarySummedIntValue(*values)
```

Demo:

```
>>> BaseIntValue(42) + BaseIntValue(81) + BaseIntValue(314)
IntermediarySummedIntValue(values=(BaseIntValue(value=42), BaseIntValue(value=81), BaseIntValue(value=314)))
>>> int(BaseIntValue(42) + BaseIntValue(81) + BaseIntValue(314))
Expensive calculation taking place
437
```

Comment: This is actually a nice trick. +1!

Answer (score 0):

`+`, `-`, etc... are **binary** operators.

```
>>> tree=ast.parse('a+b+c')
>>> astpretty.pprint(tree)
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            lineno=1,
            col_offset=0,
            value=BinOp(
                lineno=1,
                col_offset=3,
                left=BinOp(
                    lineno=1,
                    col_offset=0,
                    left=Name(lineno=1, col_offset=0, id='a', ctx=Load()),
                    op=Add(),
                    right=Name(lineno=1, col_offset=2, id='b', ctx=Load()),
                ),
                op=Add(),
                right=Name(lineno=1, col_offset=4, id='c', ctx=Load()),
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

So, no, there is no way to override those operators to get what you want.

Go with the static method.